# Embedded inline images in Dynamic tamplate (Sendgrid APis)

Tags: java, email, sendgrid, email-templates

I am using/creating Sendgrid Dynamic Template to send the email using JAVA apis.
Template has inline embeded image. I am able to see the image in the preview on template on sendgrid console but when I send the mail, then that image is not present on the mail.

Attached sendgrid console preview snapshot:

[image: Send Grid Console]

Html code block is as below:

```
<html><head></head><body><p>Hi This is NJ</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p><img alt="MyImage" src="data:image/png;base64,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"></p><p style="color:white;font-size:0px;">referenceId:{{referenceId}}</p></body></html>
```

Mail Received:

[image: Mail Received]

Let me know what I am missing here

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

While I can't find any official documentation on this anywhere, it seems that Gmail, and indeed most webmail, does not support base64 encoded images in emails.

If you are using the drag and drop editor for your SendGrid template then you can drag an image module onto the email and upload the image you want to use.

Comment: I am using Java apis to create the sendgrid template and from api I am always passing html code in the field "html_content". Is there any way where I can add the image module via api?

Comment: I can't find anything specific for creating modules when you create the template via the API. In this case I would recommend that you upload the image you want to include to a publicly available URL and then use that as the image `src`. I just tested with the SendGrid editor and that is all it does behind the scenes (the only difference is that it gives you a place to upload the image too).